# SSIS setup - Is this going to impact performance

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I am currently having two SQL database servers 2008 R2 , one containing  SSIS package and SQL job running and the other containing source and destination  databases.  In the new proposed architecture, we are planning to migrate the package to SSIS 2016. The package would sit on a box that would contain SSIS instance  and destination database would reside on another SQL 2016 server. The source database would reside on old SQL 2008 R2 server.
The SSIS package is going to transmit millions of data across the source and destination.

Do you see any issue with this architecture setup ? Ideally it would make sense to migrate the source  to the 2016 database server to avoid network latency ? Unfortunately we cant do that due to some technical reasons and need to retain the it in the old server for now. Do you feel it will have s significant impact

I would like to know any views on this architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

In your original setup you have the following schema
**(DB Server)*Src DB*** --> **(SSIS Server)*Package transformation*** --> **(DB Server)*Dest DB***
So, you have the data traveling over the network two times - from **DB Server** to **SSIS Server** and back. It does not matter that *Src DB* resides on the same server with *Dest DB*; all processing is done on **SSIS Server**.
On your new setup you have
**(Legacy DB Server)*Src DB*** --> **(SSIS 2016 Server)*Package transformation*** --> **(SQL 2016 DB Server)*Dest DB***
The same amount of data is moved over the network; the only difference is that Src and Dest servers are different. So, from network load perspective the new design is very close to the original.
Moving *Src DB* to **SQL 2016 DB Server** might benefit from performance and other improvements of SQL 2016 over SQL 2008. Away from it, you will have data traveling over the network like your original case.
If you are really concerned about network traffic and latency, you can move SSIS Package execution to the same server as Src and Dst DB, using shared memory OLEDB provider. However, it might be bad for overall performance, since both SQL Dbs and SSIS will compete for the same CPU and RAM.